# Remotely turn on and turn off UWP app

Tags: uwp

I am working on a `UWP` app for a desktop. I want to remotely turn on and turn off the `UWP` app may be either from a mobile app or anything best suited.

I intend to use the app only on laptop.

Can anyone help me how can I start or what should I use to achieve this. Someone suggested me to use `Azure Service Bus`.

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'turning off' an UWP app. You can always use a raw push notification to be handled by your app. I think there's some reserved app capability available for being able to close the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *project rome* APIs which are intended for connected apps and devices communications.
This API allows you to discover remote device, launch an app on a remote device and communicate with an app on another device.

You can find some documentation about this API here: [Connected apps and devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/connected-apps-and-devices)